# Segmentation Fault when call iswctype function in libc.so.6 using python ctypes

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes, libc

I'm learning ctypes module in python. I have the following code:

## code

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6")
print(libc)
for x in "我学Python!":
    print("'%s'" % x, libc.iswalpha(
       ord(x)
    ))

libc.wctype.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]
alpha_wctype = libc.wctype(b'print')
print(type(alpha_wctype))
libc.iswctype.restype = ctypes.c_int
print(libc.iswctype(ord("我"), alpha_wctype))
```

## output

```
3.7.7 (default, May  7 2020, 21:25:33) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
<CDLL '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6', handle 7f1d5b9e24f0 at 0x7f1d5a498f10>
'我' 1
'学' 1
'P' 1024
'y' 1024
't' 1024
'h' 1024
'o' 1024
'n' 1024
'!' 0
<class 'int'>
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f1d5b9dd740 (most recent call first):
  File "test2.py", line 15 in <module>
[1]    12178 segmentation fault  python -X faulthandler test2.py
```

So why the last line produced a segmentation fault, how can I use iswctype correctly using ctypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wctype` doesn't return an `int` but rather a `wctype_t`. Python doesn't have a portable `ctypes` type for this, but it's probably an `unsigned long` on your system, so do `libc.wctype.restype = ctypes.c_ulong`. Similarly, you need to specify the argument types for `iswctype`, like this: `libc.iswctype.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_ulong]`. By not doing those things, you were truncating the `alpha_wctype` value, which was causing the segfault.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I thought these types are c_ushort. But how can i makesure these types, without searching the libc code?  Is there any pythonic way?

Comment: @MengZhao I don't think so. I looked through https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html but I don't see any better way to do it.